# The placeholder is not showing up at first instance because of i put value={newTodo} and i know that in first instance "newTodo" is empty. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The "newTodo" state variable is empty in the first instance when i load the page, that's why the placeholder is not displaying, it act as if there is zero value in newTodo variable so placeholder is not showing up in the first instance, but after i enter a text then placeholder shows up.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const ToDo = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState(" ");

    let globalID = 0;
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setNewTodo("");
        setTodo((oldTodo) => {
            return [...oldTodo, newTodo]
        });
        

    }
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setNewTodo(e.target.value);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="header">Building To Do App</h1>
            <section className='flex justify-center mt-8'>
            <div className='border border-indigo-800 w-1/2 flex flex-col text-center h-96'>
                <h2 className=' h-16 flex justify-center items-center bg-pink-600 text-white' >To-Do List</h2>
                
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="mt-6">

                <input  placeholder='Add a Item' type="text" onChange={handleInput} name="todo" id="todo" value={newTodo} className='w-1/2 h-12 rounded-sm border-b-4 border-indigo-500 text-xl bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none text-black' />
                <button className='bg-pink-600 rounded-full w-12 h-12 mx-4 hover:bg-green-700'>+</button>
                
                </form>
                
                <ol className='todoList'>
                        {todo.map((items) => {
                        return <li key={globalID++} >{items}</li>
                        } )}
                </ol>
            </div>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default ToDo
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the default value `newTodo` value `" "` that's issue !

```
const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState();
```

Remove `" "` from `useState();` solve the issue !